# Can I make Jest report test results incrementally after each test?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, reporting

I've searched around a bit and did not find much about this. By default Jest only creates test reports after each test suite as far as I know. I'd like it to report a test's success after each test run just like mocha. I need it because when I'm running it on TeamCity I'd like to see the incremental progress. Is there any way to enable this? Thanks!

What I'd like to achieve (pseudo):

```
...
[some timestamps] [SOME_LEVEL]: some logs
...
Report: Test Test#1 Passed
...
[some other timestamps] [SOME_LEVEL]: some other logs
...
Report: Test Test#2 Failed
...
etc
```

By default Jest works like this:

```
...
[some timestamps] [SOME_LEVEL]: some logs  
...
[some other timestamps] [SOME_LEVEL]: some other logs
...
Report: Test Test#1 Passed
Report: Test Test#2 Failed
```

Comment: Maybe you could write your own log with [testResultsProcessor](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#testresultsprocessor-string)

Comment: I think there should be standard way to do this. Most other frameworks do support this kind of reporting. If I myself have to write something like this then I'll simply choose another framework instead. I like the better error messages that can be found in Jest but it is not worth the extra effort for me.

Comment: If you enable CodeCoverage in the Jest configuration, instead of command line, then run Jest in watch mode, not watch all, I think the coverage is just of the changed files.